# Why is my JFrame image not changing the icon?

Tags: java, image, swing, imageicon

I am trying to change the image icon on a JFrame and it is not showing up. I have tried both the absolute path to my desktop and then the path that I have in Eclipse. Why is this not working. I have looked on stackoverflow and this is how it looks like that it is probably done, but for some reason the code below is not working.

code:

```
package TestMenu;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TestJFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public TestJFrame() {
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\itpr13266\\workspace\\TestMenu\\src\\TestMenu\\img\\s.jpg");
        setIconImage(img.getImage());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(117, 105, 10, 10);
        contentPane.add(panel);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestJFrame frame = new TestJFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

No exception was thrown.

The code is fix now. I had the wrong image format type.

Code that does not work:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MenuLookDemo {
    JTextArea output;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar;
        JMenu menu, submenu;
        JMenuItem menuItem;
        JRadioButtonMenuItem rbMenuItem;
        JCheckBoxMenuItem cbMenuItem;

        menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        menu = new JMenu("A Menu");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
        menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                "The only menu in this program that has menu items");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("A text-only menu item",
                                 KeyEvent.VK_T);
        //menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_T); //used constructor instead
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_1, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        menuItem.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                "This doesn't really do anything");
        menu.add(menuItem);

        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("src\\TestMenu\\img\\stop.jpg");
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Both text and icon", icon);
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem(icon);
        menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
        menu.add(menuItem);

        //a group of radio button menu items
        menu.addSeparator();
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("A radio button menu item");
        rbMenuItem.setSelected(true);
        rbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        rbMenuItem = new JRadioButtonMenuItem("Another one");
        rbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
        group.add(rbMenuItem);
        menu.add(rbMenuItem);

        //a group of check box menu items
        menu.addSeparator();
        cbMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("A check box menu item");
        cbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        menu.add(cbMenuItem);

        cbMenuItem = new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Another one");
        cbMenuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_H);
        menu.add(cbMenuItem);


        menu.addSeparator();
        submenu = new JMenu("A submenu");
        submenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_S);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("An item in the submenu");
        menuItem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(
                KeyEvent.VK_2, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
        submenu.add(menuItem);

        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Another item");
        submenu.add(menuItem);
        menu.add(submenu);

        //Build second menu in the menu bar.
        menu = new JMenu("Another Menu");
        menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
        menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
                "This menu does nothing");
        menuBar.add(menu);

        return menuBar;
    }

    public Container createContentPane() {
        //Create the content-pane-to-be.
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);

        //Create a scrolled text area.
        output = new JTextArea(5, 30);
        output.setEditable(false);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);

        //Add the text area to the content pane.
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return contentPane;
    }

    /** Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid. */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = MenuLookDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MenuLookDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        MenuLookDemo demo = new MenuLookDemo();
        frame.setJMenuBar(demo.createMenuBar());
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.setSize(450, 260);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Error:**  (From the above example and it is just like the example above which I got to work)

```
    Couldn't find file: src\TestMenu\img\stop.jpg
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? I ran up some sample code that is similar to yours and its working. The only thing I can think of is that the file path must be incorrect.

Comment: I recieved no exceptions that is what was strange. Normally if it cannot find the file it throws a file not found exception. But nothing in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be that BMP is not supported. If you follow the Java source code from the constructor of ImageIcon you end up at:

```
(java.awt.Toolkit.java)

/**
 * Returns an image which gets pixel data from the specified file, 
 * whose format can be either GIF, JPEG or PNG. 
 * ...
 */
 public abstract Image getImage(String filename);
```

According to [this article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html), ImageIcon supports GIF, JPEG, or PNG. Try converting your image to another format using something like GIMP or Paint and see if you get the same results.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getImage%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: I just checked it on my system, converting a png, jpg, or gif into a bmp by changing the file extension works fine. However, creating a fresh bmp does not work. So, changing the file extension is not enough. Using paint etc to save as a different file extension does seem to perform the correct conversion to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me, I substituted a jpeg on my c drive and changed the path accordingly.  It placed the icon in the upper left corner of the frame.  Try simplifying your path to C:\filename and see if it works.

Comment: That's really not an answer.

Comment: that could be a comment instead of an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Swing {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ////jframe = a GUI(graphical user interface) window to add components
     JFrame frame =  new JFrame();//we are creating a new frame 
     frame.setVisible(true);//this helps to make the frame visible 
     frame.setSize(500, 500);//this is for resizing our window into any size
     frame.setTitle("Manoj sai");//to set the title for the window 
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//normally when we hit X button it will hide but it will not close so to close that we have to give that when we press X exit_on_close
     frame.setResizable(false);//this makes the window not resizeable we cant resize the window 
     //ImageIcon will help to keep images in GUI(its a separate class)
     ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\manoj\\Pictures\\logos\\logo.jpg");//creates an image icon
     frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());//sets the selected image for icon for our window 
}
}
```

*here use the file path which is in your computer then u will get ur icon displayed after importing to the eclipse use the path which is in ur local disc c `ex:"C:\\Users\\manoj\\Pictures\\logos\\logo.jpg"`*